# Corruption of a TrueCrypt file

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, file-corruption, cryptography

Dear superuser people,

this is my first question on the site so if I'm doing something wrong I apologize in advance  :-)

I've been using TrueCrypt for a few years now, not knowing they stopped developing it a year ago.

In my C: drive, I had an encrypted folder of 50GB which contains all sort of super important encrypted data.
It worked perfectly until last week when I tried cutting and pasting my encrypted file of 50GB onto an external hard drive.
Something is obviously wrong with my computer / hard drive and it was bearly moving the file, even after many hours of wait.
When I tried to shut the file transfer window after a few hours (!!) of not doing much, it wouldn't shut and it slowed my computer to the point it got stuck and I had to force shut it down.

When I turned my computer back on, I saw the file had moved onto the hard drive but I could no longer mount it and view the files inside.

I get the following error everytime I put the password for my encrypted file:

**"Incorrect password or not a Truecrypt volume."**

Now I know for a fact I got the right password, so I believe the file has gotten corrupt.

I am using the latest version of TrueCrypt.

**I tried moving the file back to my computer from the hard drive but it still wouldn't open and I get the same error.**

I can't lose my data because it's super valuable to me.

Thanks in advance,

Jin-G

Comment: Tried checking the checkbox for using the backup header yet?

Comment: Most types of OS do not delete the old file in a Move operation until transfer is complete. Even after the transfer, there is a good chance the original file has not yet been deleted, only *marked as deleted* in the file system (unless you've written additional data to the disk). Your best chance may be to try to recover the *original* file, as it appears the copy has been corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

TrueCrypt has an option 'Use backup header embedded in volume if available', which can be found under 'Mount Volume with options'. In case that doesn't help, it is very unlikely that the corrupt TrueCrypt container can be restored at all. There's nothing practical you could try. The way to recover your files is to restore a backup you have made earlier.

If you don't have one, your best bet is to try data recovery tools on the hard drive on which the container was initially stored. Large encrypted files make very lousy candidates for this to work, but if you're lucky, some of the data may yet be salvaged. As always, don't use the drive. Make a duplicate and take it out. Attempting to move the container back to the original hard disk has already greatly diminished your chance of success.

Comment: BIG +1 *"Attempting to move the container back to the original hard disk has already greatly diminished your chance of success"* and *"restore a backup you have made earlier"*. Backup copies of data, and headers, is super important, especially with encryption

Comment: I have tried to use the backup header embedded in the volume but since I made no back up it doesn't work.

Any other ideas you guys might have? 
Which recovery tools would you suggest?
Also, I have a backup of the file itself I have made on a disk on key a long time ago but this backup wouldn't mount as well..

Comment: P.S. 
I have copied the encrypted file back to the computer and kept a copy of it on the external hard drive and not moved it as in cut pase, therefore the file is still on the external drive after the sketchy transfer. Maybe that would increase my chances?

Comment: @JinG: Having multiple copies of the container that all seem to be corrupted would increase the likelihood that the file can be pieced back together, but it is by no means an easy task. If the data is worth the money to you, you may want to get a data recovery specialist involved.